# switching color of buttons after onclick

Tags: android

i have several buttons.i want when i click on any of the buttons its color should be changed and other buttons should remain the same.Next time when i click on other button its color should be change and other remain the same(or in by defalut state),and so on.
here is my code

```
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.bt1:
bt11.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.Multiple);
bt12.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
break;

case R.id.bt2:
bt12.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.Multiple);
bt11.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
break;
}
```

but when i pressed button bt11 very first time its color becomes CYAN and when i press bt12 then its color becomes CYAN and the first button i.e bt11 comes in its default state but next time everything is going wrong both the buttons remain in the CYAN color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
the problem in your code is you are putting a color filter on the  button's bg property and it will remain even if you change the bg instead set the filter on the imgand set it as bg fr btn

```
 switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bt1:
        Drawable d=b11.getBackground();
        d.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        b11.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        b12.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    break;

    case R.id.bt2:
    //b2.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    Drawable dd=b12.getBackground();
    dd.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    b12.setBackgroundDrawable(dd);
    b11.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
button.setBackgroundColor( android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: I have also tried this but it is changing the shape of the button.

Answer (score 0):

"next time everything is going wrong both the buttons remain in the CYAN color" because when you click other button, you are only changing other button background but color remained the same I guess. You have to change background color also.

```
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.bt1:
bt11.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.Multiple);
bt12.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
bt12.setBackgroundColor(Black);
break;

case R.id.bt2:
bt12.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.Multiple);
bt11.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
bt11.setBackgroundColor(Black);
break;
}
```