# Temporarily change drawable color

Tags: java, android

In one app I'm developing I'm trying to programatically create an `ImageButton` that is a copy of the selected `ImageButton`, but the image is colorized in a different way, let's say red.

If I use the `PowerDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`:

```
clonebutton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Then even the original `ImageButton` changes its color to red since they share the same `drawable`. Is there a way to apply the filter only on the clonebutton without using two different `drawables`? For instance is it possible in some way to put a colorize layer on top of clonebutton without editing the `drawable`?

**Update**
I set the drawable as mutable:

```
Drawable d = swipebutton.getDrawable();
d.mutate();
d.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
swipebutton.setImageDrawable(d);
```

This prevents my clonebutton to share the state of its `drawable` to other `views`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Drawable buttonBackground = clonebutton.getDrawable();
buttonBackground = buttonBackground.mutate();
buttonBackground.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

> Make this drawable mutable. This operation cannot be reversed. A
>   mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other
>   drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties
>   of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables
>   instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you
>   modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive
>   the same modification. Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will
>   have no effect.

Comment: The answer came so fast that I could not accept it at that moment because of my low reputation, but this definitely works!

Answer (score 1):

On Lollipop you don't have to do this programmatic, i.e. colorfilters, at all if you don't want to. You can do it just by setting a tint on an xml drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:tint="@color/red_tint"/>
```

This might not work if you have an unlimiited number of colors but if they are limited this is a really good option. [Check out my blog post for more information](http://toastdroid.com/2014/12/06/byte-of-toast-tinting-drawables-on-lollipop/).

Comment: Great answer I was already trying this but it did not work since I used `#000` instead of `#ff000000`. That this attibute is permitted in Lollipop is also not documented. They should add this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable d=clonebutton.getDrawable()
d.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
clonebutton.setDrawable(d);
```

try this: or take the below code as per your need

```
 switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.bt1:
    Drawable d=b11.getBackground();
    d.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    b11.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    b12.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
break;

case R.id.bt2:
//b2.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
Drawable dd=b12.getBackground();
dd.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

b12.setBackgroundDrawable(dd);
b11.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
break;
}
```

[switching color of buttons after onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106262/switching-color-of-buttons-after-onclick/12106856#12106856)

Comment: In my case I want to colorize the drawable and not the background. Two buttons share the same drawable but not the same background and this explains why it works, but it's not what i want to achieve

Comment: you can get the drawable and store it in a temp variable and applay filter then set it the background over here also shares the common androwid drawable for button